# Embedding PHP into HTML

Tags: php, html, textarea, embedding

```
<?php
If  ( isset ($_POST['name'] ) )  {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    if (!empty ($name))     {

        $sentence = $name . " is the best footballer of his generation. ";

    }   else     {
        echo "Please enter a name";
    }

}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!-- ********************************** -->
<form action="form3.php" method="POST">

Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Send">

</form>

<textarea rows="7" cols="30">  <?php echo $sentence; ?>  </textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

---

The code works just fine, but for some reason the text inside the textarea shows this error

**Notice**:  Undefined variable: sentence in **C:\xampp\htdocs\form3.php** on line **29**

### Please help.

Comment: It's a scope issue. You're defining `$sentence` only if the form has been submitted; but displaying it no matter what. Try initialising it to a blank string before your `if` statement.

Comment: Are you sure `$_POST['name']` isset?

Comment: People are offering workarounds without clearly explaining the error. You don't have to declare variables in PHP, but a variable has to be assigned a value before it can be referred to. This current problem is related to scope but that isn't the main cause (if the condition isn't met it still wouldn't be assigned a value).

Comment: It isn't actually a scope issue at all - PHP doesn't have block-level scope. You just need to define `$sentence` at the beginning of the PHP, giving it an initial value, so that it will be available to refer to later.

Comment: I understood the problem from your first comment.  I used the first option in the first answer and I defined $sentence in the beginning of the PHP. It worked. Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

$sentence is only initialized when this statement is true: `if (!empty ($name))     {`.

To avoid the error, put `$sentence = "";` above the if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using different options:

1- define `$sentence` at top of the page such as:

```
$sentence = '';
```

2- or use isset($sentence) before printing it:

```
<?php echo isset($sentence)? $sentence : ''; ?>
```

Comment: I mean the first option.

Comment: Why would the first option be better? In larger applications, you don't necessarily want hundreds if not thousands of variables declared as empty strings. Maybe for this, but overall shorthand php is better.